# Background image not appearing in pygame

Tags: python, pygame

My code currently looks like this
    import pygame
    from pygame.locals import *

```
pygame.init()
width,height = 1080,810
keys = [False,False,False,False]
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
game_running = True
background = pygame.image.load("resources/images/background.png")
while game_running:
    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(background,(0,0))
```

When the code is run, a black window pops up, but the background isn't there.

I checked the directories to make sure the loading of the image has no issue too.

Comment: `pygame` draws in buffer in memory - you have to use `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.update()` to send buffer to video card which will display it on monitor

Answer (score 2):

`pygame` draws in buffer in RAM memory (to make animation less flicking and tearing).

You have to use `pygame.display.update()` or `pygame.display.update()` to send from buffer to video card which will display it on monitor.

```
import pygame

width = 1080
height = 810

keys = [False, False, False, False]

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))

background = pygame.image.load("resources/images/background.png").convert()

game_running = True
while game_running:

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            game_running = False
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                game_running = False

    screen.fill((0,0,0))
    screen.blit(background, (0,0))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
```

Wikipedia: [Double buffering in computer graphics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_buffering#Double_buffering_in_computer_graphics)

[image]